# How to create UIImageViews dynamically / indefinitely based on dynamic need?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I am creating an iOS program. I would like to have a scroll view, populated with UIImageViews (9 at a time, 3 per row), and depending on communication with a remote server, loads images into these views and new UIImageViews are created as needed.

I feel like I have to create a custom class for this, but I am a little lost. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have taken a look at AQGridView, and I think I would like to create something myself, so I can understand it in its entirety rather than clumsily using someone else's code.

Note: I will be dealing with hundreds, if not thousands, of images. I need to be able to do this in a dynamic way that won't murder the memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a UITableView. You get the rows for free, and the scrolling.
2. Create a custom table view cell with 3 UIImageViews. (search SO for using custom table view cells)
3. In your tableView delegate, implement the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. In this method, create your image views like:

`cell.imageView1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL1]]];`

`cell.imageView2.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL2]]];`

`cell.imageView3.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL3]]];`